# How to show a special page overlay to users who are on iPhone?

Tags: php, javascript, iphone, html

If you visit webmd from your computer you see one page, but if you visit webmd from an iPhone *not only* do you get their mobile page (which is easily enough done), they **also** show you a special overlay with a "click to close" button which invites you to download their app.

Is there a component anywhere for this?  Does anyone have any starters, links, or hints about the best way to go about doing this?  I guess in principal it's like a lightbox for photos but I'm looking for something specifically to invite downloads of the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a [smart app banner](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html)

You basically add a special meta tag to your html

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```

Include the app store id for the app you want to link to. app-argument url will be passed to the appropriate AppDelegate method.

Comment: Love this solution, thanks!  Even better than what I had in mind.